# Locked Document and Settings folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virus, malware

I don't know why but I suddenly cannot access the "Documents and Settings" folder in Windows 7.

It has the padlock icon on it. [image: locked folder] Whenever I try to change the settings in the properties>Security tab, and try to allow full control to everyone. 
It just returns an error:

[image: Error Box]

Can this be associated with virus or malware

And one more thing when I tried to end process for explorer.exe, and started it again. The pad lock icon is gone. And the "Document and Settings" folder now looks like a link.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/49582/access-denied-to-documents-and-settings-on-vista  (different questions, same answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally *Documents and Settings* does not actually exist on Windows7, though some areas of windows pretends it does for backwards compatibility. It actually redirects to `C:\Users`. So try that path instead (or perhaps E:\Users in your case).

For more information:

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/cannot-find-windows-7-document-settings/ 
http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_appdata.htm

Answer (score 1):

Document and Settings folder in Windows 7 is hidden and not accessible by default.

Answer (score 0):

Have you scanned you computer with a recovery disk to see if it finds a virus, malware or rootkit?

example: http://www.free-av.com/en/tools/12/avira_antivir_rescue_system.html

Might be a good start