# Changing the Owner of a folder back to SYSTEM

Tags: permissions, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

[image: errors]

[image: permissions]
**ISSUE1**:

This is what I get when I try to open my C:/Documents and Settings.Although I am the owner of the computer I was denied permissions to open the folder. So, I changed the owner of Documents and Settings from SYSTEM to Fasih(HP-PC\HP) and this is me. Still I cant access.

Also, I want to revert the owner back to SYSTEM, just in case to prevent anything stupid. So I retraced the steps and now.. I cant change the owner back to SYSTEM (strange).
Help!

**NOTE: I realized from another question that this folder doesn't exist any more. So please tell me how to revert the Owner back to SYSTEM**

Comment: Came to know after I lent him mine, a lil late

Comment: no no, I changed the permissions on C:/ Drive to try to access Documents and Settings

Comment: I will rephrase the entire questions!

Comment: Changing permissions on the system drive C: is a bad idea, back up your data and reinstall the OS, too many different permissions on sub folders on C, may be impossible to restore them.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly, that your drive letter C is on the external HDD and not your system volume? While this is possible it is quite uncommon. If the external drive behaves weird, check it's S.M.A.R.T. status with a tool like GSmartcontrol. Do *not* attempt to write to it (chkdsk, changing ACLs) until you know it is healthy. Depending on the worth of your files, do a sector based backup immediately. You might get better results if you access the drive directly and not through a USB bridge which you probably use at the moment.

Comment: Rephrasing the question has been done!!!

Comment: and I changed the permissions on C:/Documents and Settings . Disaster Averted! my bad in typing, nervousness has gottn the better of me

Comment: Putting two completely different problems in one question is a really bad idea. I suggest you to remove your first question to prevent your question from being closed as it is likely answered in http://superuser.com/questions/49582/access-denied-to-documents-and-settings-on-vista anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the owner should not matter, you can change it back to the default by running `icacls "C:\Documents and Settings\" /setowner SYSTEM`

Looks like official documentation for Windows 7 is missing but you can find it for Windows Server here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(v=ws.10).aspx - Behavior should not differ.

Comment: Well, if the owner doesnt matter then I wont worry about it. How does the owner matter anyways?

Comment: Being the owner of a file system object *always* allows you to change permissions on that object, even if you do not have the explicit right to change permissions for that object. This is why you had to become the owner of the junction point to change the permissions. Learn more about permissions in Windows NT based systems on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783530(WS.10).aspx.